# android xml parsing nodes with same name

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml where the parent and child node has same name .
The xml is

```
<response>
<cmd>abcr</cmd>
<success>1</success>
<response>
<user_login>....</user_login>
<user_email>..</user_email>
    </response>
<errCode>0</errCode>
<errText/>
</response>
```

ie i have a response within response .
I need to extract the value of userlogin

i have code

```
doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
            NodeList responseList = doc.getElementsByTagName("response");
            Element response = (Element) responseList.item(0);
            String name = parser.getValue(response, "user_login");
```

It is not working correctly . What should i change to make it correct.
please help

Comment: You need to take and maintain flag value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user_login");
String name = nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question...

```
xmlMessagesCount = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("messages").item(0).getChildNodes().length;
```